# Ranking of multiple raters with partially overlapping assessments

Tags: maximum-likelihood, modeling, references, binary-data, ranking

###### Ranking of Raters and Cases

I am looking for a method for ranking a set of raters with partially overlapping binary assessments. I also want to rank the cases according to their difficulty.

###### Context

I have dataset with *N* cases, $\{c_n\}_{n=1}^N$, and *M* raters, $\{r_m\}_{m=1}^M$, where each rater $r_m$ has assessed *some number* of cases, and where each case $c_n$ has been assessed by *some number* of raters.

###### Assumptions:

- The number of cases assessed varies between readers, and the number of raters assessed by varies between cases.
- The distribution of the assessments, i.e. the rater-case-pairs is unknown, i.e. the cases have **not** (*necessarily*) been assigned to raters uniformly at random.
- The graph, formed by the rater-case-pairs, is connected, i.e. it has a single connected component. (*Hence, there are no issues with "isolated clusters", which would unable a global ranking.*)
- (*If necessary, you can assume that $N=3000$, $M=50$, that each rater has assessed at least 500 cases, and that each case has been assessed by at at least 5 raters. However, is is primarily to give a better idea of the problem – I general answer is preferred.*)

###### Illustration:

The data would look something like this

```
         case_1  case_2  case_3  case_4   ... case_N
rater_1  -1       1       0       1   ...     1
rater_2   1       0      -1       1   ...     0
rater_3   0      -1       0       1   ...     1
rater_4  -1       1       1       1   ...    -1
...      ...     ...     ...     ...  ...    ...
rater_M  -1       0       0       1   ...     0
```

where

- The rater *correctly* classified the case: 1
- The rater *incorrectly* classified the case: -1
- The rater did *not* asses the case: 0

###### Initial Thoughts

Personally, I believe some form of maximum-likelihood estimation (MLE) algorithm can be used to solve this problem.

###### Clarification

The accuracy of the raters, and the difficulty of the cases are unknown and potentially subject to large variability. Therefore, simply aggregating over cases or readers will not yield accurate results. (*Simply aggregating would work if the cases would have been assigned to raters uniformly at random, and each rater would have assessed a high enough number of cases. However, since this is not not true, the "skill" of the raters and the difficulty of cases have to be modelled (explicitly(?)).*)

###### Suggestions, Guidance, and References

I would like some guidance and suggested approaches, and to be pointed to relevant literature. *(Please, also state what assumptions are made for a suggested approach.)*

### Update

Data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cJ9wF1nGWtXbp4iqu-O9Ohp8Ml5dwkR1/view?usp=sharing) (1.5 MB) and read with `torch.load('X.pt')`.

The distribution of the accuracy of raters:
[image: rater_acc]

The distribution of the accuracy on cases:
[image: case_acc]
35% cases are correctly classified by all raters.

Comment: If each case is assessed by ~15 raters, and raters are ~80% correct, and all these are independent, then in each case, the majority opinion of those raters has a ~98% chance of being correct. So you can start by ranking raters based on how often they agree with those majority opinions, and ranking the cases as more difficult when the opinions are more divided.

Comment: @MattF. Thank you for your comment. I have adjusted my question to clarify the problem.

Comment: A straightforward approach would be to apply a generalized linear model with a binomial family and using a linear combination of the 'rater' and the 'case' as the model. An interesting aspect would be to study whether there is a more complex structure among the raters and cases, and this you could analyse with clustering or pca. If you want, then this problem can become very complex beyond the extent of something that is easily answered here.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Thanks for your comment! Could you maybe expand on your comment about the use of a generalized linear model in this context?

Comment: Are raters assigned to cases independently of each other? Otherwise one could, for example, imagine that notoriously good raters get the hard cases after these cases got controversal ratings from other raters.

Comment: @Ute So, in my real scenario, the cases actually are assigned to raters independently of each other; therefore, with enough assessments, the random assignment would solve the problem of difference in case difficulty and rater accuracy. However, in my question here, I am interested in a more general case. For example, one could want to assign to raters, cases that have "uncertain" assessments, as if e.g. 10 raters all say the same thing about a case, asking a 11th rater does not add much value. Then the resources would be better spent to get extra assessments for cases where raters disagree.

Comment: Yes, agree that one would put extra raters on the undecided cases :-). Good to know that the raters are assigned independently of each other, so you would also not try to give the hard cases to the (a priory rated) best raters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The description of the problem implies that cases have an inherent unknown "difficulty", which impacts the probability of a case being correctly classified by a rater, and that raters have a "skill" level with a similar effect. Modeling this therefore amounts to choosing some function that relates the success probability to those parameters. There are many possible ways of choosing such a function, a simple one might be:

$$P(\text{success}|\theta_n,\phi_m) = \frac{1+\theta_n\phi_m}{2}.$$

Here, $0<\theta_n<1$ is the difficulty level, $\theta_n=0$ being the most difficult, such that the best any rater can achieve is just a random choice ($P=1/2$). $0<\phi_m<1$ is similarly the skill level, such that the most skillful rater ($\phi_m=1$) can correctly classify the most easy cases with a 100% probability.

With the data $x_{nm}$ as described in the question ($x_{nm}=1$ for correct classification, $x_{nm}=-1$ for incorrect classification and $x_{nm}=0$ for no classification) the log-likelihood is (up to an irrelevant constant):

$$ \log \mathcal L = \sum_{n,m} \log(1 + x_{nm}\theta_n \phi_m)$$

and this can be maximized numerically (e.g. using gradient descent) in order to find the maximum likelihood estimators.

Notice that if we can assume that $\theta_n \phi_m \ll 1$, then the likelihood simplifies to

$$ \log \mathcal L  \approx \sum_{n,m} x_{nm}\theta_n \phi_m \equiv \mathbf \theta^T X \mathbf \phi .$$

For vectors $\theta,\phi$ with fixed norms, this is maximized by the [singular vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) that correspond to the largest singular value of the matrix $X$. So, an approximate solution can be achieved this way simply by performing a singular value decomposition of $X$.

More generally, we can write the likelihood as

$$ \log \mathcal L = \sum_{n,m} \log\left(\frac{1-x_{nm}}{2} + x_{nm}P_{nm}\right)$$

Where $P_{nm}$ is the success probability. (Notice that the expression inside the logarithm is equal to $P_{nm}$ when $x_{nm}=1$, $(1-P_{nm})$ when $x_{nm}=-1$, and a constant when $x_{nm}=0$). For a model that allow the probability to be zero, we can consider $P_{nm}=\theta_n \phi_m$ or, using unconstrained parameters, $P_{nm}=\text{Sigmoid}(w_n+v_m)=(1+e^{-(w_n+v_m)})^{-1}$. The corresponding modifications to the Python code are:

```py
return -torch.log((1-X)/2 + teta * X * phi.T).sum()
```

or

```py
return -torch.log((1-X)/2 + X * torch.sigmoid(w + v.T)).sum()
```

Comparing the maximum likelihood values of the two options with the provided data, we get a small but significant preference ($\Delta \log \mathcal L = 345.8$) for the second model. (The comparison is meaningful because the models have the same number of parameters). The MLE values for $v_m$ are: (converted to probabilities for case difficulty $w=0$)

```py
print(torch.sigmoid(v).T)
tensor([[0.8846, 0.8338, 0.8891, 0.8149, 0.9040, 0.9188, 0.8654, 0.7761, 0.8773,
         0.8976, 0.9249, 0.8826, 0.8549, 0.9055, 0.9154, 0.9490, 0.7566, 0.8934,
         0.9529, 0.8855, 0.7359, 0.8765, 0.9106, 0.8981, 0.9141, 0.9172, 0.8148,
         0.9212, 0.8592, 0.8356, 0.8787, 0.9118, 0.8324, 0.9138, 0.8882, 0.9095,
         0.8305, 0.8393, 0.8893, 0.8384, 0.8906, 0.9201, 0.7997, 0.9011, 0.8896,
         0.9143, 0.9078, 0.9124, 0.9278, 0.8945, 0.7991, 0.7544, 0.9058, 0.8708,
         0.7664, 0.8078, 0.9104, 0.8673, 0.8346, 0.8012, 0.8408, 0.7689, 0.9018,
         0.8283, 0.8363, 0.8732]], grad_fn=<PermuteBackward0>)
```

Notice that, since the data is limited, not all differences between MLE values may be statistically significant. To determine that, further analysis of statistical significance is required.

---

Maximum likelihood implementation using PyTorch:

```py
import torch

N, M = 3000, 70

#gererate random true parameters:
teta = torch.rand(N,1)
phi  = torch.rand(M,1)

#generate random data matrix X:
P = (1 + teta*phi.T)/2
X = 2*torch.bernoulli(P) - 1
#set about 70% of X entries to zero
X[torch.rand(N,M) > 0.3] = 0

#unconstrained optimization parameters, 
#such that teta = sigmoid(w) and phi=sigmoid(v) 
w = torch.randn(N,1,requires_grad=True)
v = torch.randn(M,1,requires_grad=True)

#likelihood loss function
def loss(w,v,X):
    teta = torch.sigmoid(w)
    phi = torch.sigmoid(v)
    return -torch.log(1 + teta * X * phi.T).sum()


optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([w,v],lr=0.05)

#gradient descent iterations
for iter in range(1000):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    L = loss(w,v,X)
    L.backward()
    optimizer.step()


print('true phi:')
print(phi.T)
print('MLE:')
print(torch.sigmoid(v).T)
```

output:

```
true phi:
tensor([[0.1621, 0.4545, 0.1322, 0.9994, 0.4517, 0.4210, 0.5734, 0.9993, 0.8364,
         0.7181, 0.5347, 0.8723, 0.9996, 0.0760, 0.9831, 0.7306, 0.1410, 0.8279,
         0.2426, 0.5312, 0.6453, 0.3937, 0.9949, 0.1446, 0.1909, 0.2223, 0.0982,
         0.9986, 0.7534, 0.7858, 0.0199, 0.2229, 0.1371, 0.5162, 0.1269, 0.4183,
         0.7202, 0.9995, 0.0551, 0.7844, 0.0248, 0.0022, 0.2925, 0.9989, 0.0608,
         0.9984, 0.6897, 0.8560, 0.9992, 0.1023, 0.8478, 0.8740, 0.5565, 0.2198,
         0.9949, 0.5519, 0.8228, 0.3855, 0.3905, 0.4450, 0.3783, 0.3177, 0.8440,
         0.4595, 0.4974, 0.3771, 0.7208, 0.8438, 0.9292, 0.0892]],
       grad_fn=<PermuteBackward0>)
MLE:
tensor([[0.1528, 0.4522, 0.1803, 0.9994, 0.5803, 0.4260, 0.5195, 0.9988, 0.9986,
         0.6797, 0.4950, 0.9968, 0.9997, 0.0402, 0.9998, 0.7741, 0.1542, 0.9965,
         0.1423, 0.4255, 0.6306, 0.3968, 0.9996, 0.1225, 0.1858, 0.1826, 0.0672,
         0.9973, 0.9987, 0.9986, 0.0558, 0.2186, 0.1733, 0.4893, 0.0905, 0.4301,
         0.7361, 0.9985, 0.0657, 0.9991, 0.0501, 0.0018, 0.2379, 0.9986, 0.0548,
         0.9984, 0.6548, 0.9981, 0.9991, 0.1299, 0.7725, 0.9949, 0.5826, 0.2785,
         0.9995, 0.6145, 0.8397, 0.3643, 0.3875, 0.4685, 0.3267, 0.2936, 0.9969,
         0.5136, 0.5735, 0.3453, 0.6652, 0.9958, 0.9984, 0.1792]],
       grad_fn=<PermuteBackward0>)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have tried to implement this, but without success. I have written a question on StackOverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76309737/parametric-optimization-in-python) but have not received an answer that has helped me solve my problem. With the existing suggested approaches, the code does not convert to a reasonable solution, and definitely not an optimal solution. Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @Filip I'm not familiar with SciPy's optimizations functions, but in general numerical optimization works better on unconstrained problems  (which can be achieved with re-parametrization) and of course using gradients when possible. I've added a pytorch implementation that takes about 1-2 seconds to converge to a solution.

Comment: I end up with over 80% of the values in phi turning to 1. Is there a way to avoid this?
(I also end up with 45 % the values in theta as 1 and 15% as 0.)

Comment: @Filip with what data ? notice that if raters have no mistakes, then 1 is the correct MLE (there is no way to distinguish them from a perfect rater). You might also want to look at some sort of confidence intervals for those parameters

Comment: I updated my question and added a link to my data. All raters have an accuracy in the interval 71.1-88.5%.

Comment: @Filip Interesting. Notice that in this model, the worst cases can't have less then 0.5 success probability, which is what you would expect if the raters were just classifying them randomly. But in your data, there are cases with close to 0 success probability (they are not just difficult, but "misleading" in the sense that everyone gets them wrong). You can change the model to allow the success probability to get down to zero, which is more appropriate for your data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you have any input on how this model can be changed to accommodate this?

(Comment: These can be thought of as "adversary examples". While the higher skill/experience of a rater would increase the chances of getting it right (generally), these cases have traits suggestive of the other class. So, a top rater might learn to still distinguish these cases, but a very inexperienced rater might not be able to, and hence "be tricked" to misclassify the case.)

Comment: @Filip See the update to the answer